# IN-PHASE & QUADRATURE SINUSOIDAL COMPONENTS

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

I was reading about IN-PHASE & QUADRATURE SINUSOIDAL COMPONENTS. And there is a part I don't understand. Is this part:

Fom trig identity:$$\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$$

we have, \begin{align}x(t)&= A\sin(\omega t+\phi)\\
&=A\sin(\phi+\omega t)
\\&=[A\sin(\phi)]\cos(\omega t)+[A\cos(\phi)]\sin(\omega t)
\\&=A_1\cos(\omega t)+A_2\sin(\omega t)\end{align}

I don't understand how the final equation was obtained.

Comment: It's best not to use all caps even in titles—people feel shouted at, or that you're demanding they look at your question rather than the surrounding ones. That nay well be where the downvote came from.

Comment: that was not my intention, the title was cap from the website but appreciate the advise and will take in consideration next time

Comment: Ah I see. It's worth being careful about, anyway, because people can react quite strongly to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just $$A_1=A\sin\phi$$ and $$A_2=A\cos\phi.$$